# Virtually adjusting screen size and position

Tags: display, external-display

I'm working on a display piece which is an LCD monitor that is partially covered and needs to be running an application in full screen in the uncovered portion of the screen.

I have tried xvidtune on linux which gives me mode errors and switchresx on macosx which only seems to change resolution but not reposition nor resize (it stretches to full screen anyways).

I'm wondering if there's anyway to do this? Practically, I have access to any OS.

Comment: It is physically covered or software covered?

Comment: Physically covered

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was by converting the visuals to video and using processing.org to write up a quick player to resize, position and play it. Unfortunately performance for HD playback was significantly less than VLC and there was no audio, but it worked.